# Java plugin doesn't work in Chrome -- how can I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, java

This used to work fine until a week or so ago, and I am not sure what has changed since then.  I have just uninstalled what seems to be all the JVM stuff on my machine and reinstalled with the latest recommended Java version from java.com (1.6, update 23).  The plugin works fine in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome it fails and the pages that try to use the plugin act as if Java is not installed.  I have tried this in both Chrome 8 and Chrome 9 with the same result.

How can I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's Windows 7.

Comment: http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml is what i read and it helped me figure out how to make java work on chrome.

Comment: @chastity: I have the same problem, and the Java plugin doesn't even appear in Chrome's list of plugins, so the java.com link above doesn't help. Looks like it's the 64-bit Java vs. 32-bit Chrome issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using 64-bit Windows, only IE supports 64-bit Java. Chrome and Firefox will only work if you install the 32-bit Java.

[For more details - Google support](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=640554c8e44f58da&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! I had discovered this combination worked a while back but never updated my question.

Comment: Had the same problem. Uninstalling 64-bit Java and installing the 32-bit version fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

it is an easy fix , I also had a lot of trouble with java in chrome

go to this web site http://www.java.com/en/javafx/

chose the 32 bit java FX for most people download and install your problem is ficex

I still have problem with emails though

Answer (score 2):

Just now I ran into this issue, which was caused by an MSI installer trying to update Java and fracking things up. Basically Chrome looks at registry to find a better java version than the System32 one, so it accesses this registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins inhere @java.com/JavaPlugin,version=x.x.x is where the RIGHT path of the plugin is defined. Check that Path entry against the actual path and if it's not matching, that this is the issue. In a 32 bit Windows 7 it should be (or mine is) "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll".

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me.  Also, if you don't have write access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, you can copy the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins hive to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MozillaPlugins and modify it there to update the Java plugin for the current user.

Comment: Hmmm, actually my current settings showed the correct version for the plugin, but Chrome hangs when I try to use the plugin.  Will let you know if I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add URL of the site that you have problems with to the trusted sites in the Java control panel. Then, it will ask you if you want to run Java when you open the page.

This works across browsers.

On the OS X side, if you can't access the control panel, you can whitelist a site by adding it to the file `/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/security/exception.sites`. You'll have to create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I did all the above however after half an hour still cannot get it to run. I reviewed all steps, I already did correct. Eventually found that although I had closed the chrome user interface, the service still running which means chrome has not yet been restarted, so I killed that chrome process running in background, and IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

I agree about the 32 bit Java for Chrome. Anyway, after installing Java for the gazillionth time, still not finding the plugin in chrome, I went to the control panel and clicked on Java 32bit. The Java Control Panel opened. Under the security tab I checked Enable Java Content in the Browser. Under the Advanced tab I checked the box under Java Plugin. Restart chrome and voila! :) Hope this works for you; I've been dealing with this problem for at least a month.

Answer (score 0):

In a tab in Chrome type the following into the omnibar to open the Plugin list: `chrome://plugins/`. A list of installed plug-ins will be displayed. Find the Java plugin, then check the box "Always allowed".

Answer (score 0):

Since version 45, Google Chrome [no longer supports Java applets](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).

Answer (score 0):

If your try to run an applet the latest version of Google Chrome removed support for NPAPI.to enable it go To Chrome open a new tab and paste the line bellow in it and press enter

Chrome://flags/#enable-npapi

then activate the option.

or use an old Firefox or chrome version.