# Does a Java plugin for Chrome exists that does not use NPAPI?

Tags: google-chrome, java, plugins, browser-plugin, npapi

This is my follow-up question to "[Java plugin doesn't work in Chrome — how can I fix this?](https://superuser.com/q/231940/11720)".

[Google writes](http://g.co/npapi) that they will completely remove NPAPI support in Chrome 45.

**My question:**

Is there an alternative Plugin for Chrome (or a completely different way) that allows me to use Java in Chrome beyond version 45?

**Update 1:**

Oracle also has [an information page about NPAPI and Chrome](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).

Comment: There are no alternate Java plug-ins at this time.  Oracle will have to release an update.  The guidence they provided after Sept 2015 is sound.

Comment: Someone suggests to use [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) but that sounds like a really dirty workaround.